# Symfony2 and MongoDB Annotations / Mapping not recognized

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, doctrine-mongodb

I followed the steps descriped in [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html). But when i run `doctrine:mapping:info` or `doctrine:generate:entities` doctrine ignores my file.

Here is the code, maybe someone has an advice.

autoload.php

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var $loader ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();

return $loader;
```

composer.json

```
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
```

config.yml:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

entity:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Document/Product.php
namespace Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
* @MongoDB\Document
*/
class Product
{
/**
* @MongoDB\Id
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @MongoDB\String
*/
protected $name;

/**
* @MongoDB\Float
*/
protected $price;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### wrong namespace/folder :)

```
namespace Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Entity;
```

should be

```
namespace Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Document;
```

The documents usually live in the *Document* folder.

*Entity* folder/namespace is for ORM not ODM.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#creating-a-document-class).

**Wrong command**

for mongodb / doctrine odm you need to use ...

```
app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AnchorbrandsLandingpageBundle
```

... while `doctrine:generate:entities` is for doctrine orm.